# What is the meaning of the address of a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

If we have code:

```
int b = 10;
int* a = &b;
std::cout << a << " " << &a << " ";
```

As the result, the addresses are different.

But what's the meaning of address of a pointer?

A pointer has the value of a variable's address, since we have a varaible in memory. But we don't have the value of address stored in memory, so why we have the address of an address?

Maybe I have some misunderstandings, thank you for your help.

Comment: Address of a pointer is what you would assign to a pointer to a pointer

Comment: Both `a` and `b` are variables stored in memory. Both of the variable's memory have addresses.

Comment: `std::cout` does not belong in a C question. Are you using a C++ compiler? If so, it's a C++ question.

Comment: *"But we don't have the value of address stored in memory"* - actually we do. Pointers can be stored in memory (as named variables - lvalues) just like any other type of object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... Please don't change the meaning of your questions or post answers in edits to your questions; **post answers as answers only**. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember an address on your machine is going to be, itself, a 32 or 64-bit value (depending on your system architecture).

In your example, you have the integer b that stores the value 10 in some address, let's call it address 500

Then you have a pointer a, which stores the value 500, and IT has its own address.

What's the point? You can actually have double-pointers (or more).

You understand that in

```
char* string = "hello";
```

string is a pointer to the beginning of an array of characters

Then

```
char** strings;
```

is a pointer to a char*. That's how you could do an array of arrays, for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << a << " " << &a<<" ";
```

Yes ,both are different .

**1.** `a` has been assigned address of `b` , so it prints address of `b`.

**2.** `&a` prints address of pointer `a` itself .

And `a` and `b` don't have same address.

It's similar(to understand) to this example -

```
int b=9;
```

If you print `b` you get its value i.e `9` but if you print `&b` you gets its address , and in no ways they will be same .

Same is the case with pointers.

> A pointer has the value of a variable's address, since we have a variable in memory. But we don't have the value of address stored in memory, so why we have the address of an address?

We declare a variable (pointers , array , just `int`, `char`)  these all are declared in program and are stored in memory . As these are stored in memory ,they have their unique address.

Answer (score 1):

> A pointer has the value of a variable's address

I assume by *a variable* you mean *the object corresponding to the variable*. Nonetheless, this is not strictly true, and it's the edgecases where we start to make distinctions between *addresses* and *pointer values*.

There are *pointer values* that don't *point at objects* at all. Consider null pointers, for example.

Addresses, by definition, do point at objects... or functions.

> what's the meaning of address of a pointer?

The term *address of a pointer* makes sense if you can imagine a variable declared to store a pointer (e.g. `T *var;`) and you take the address of it (`&var`).

> so why we have the address of an address?

An address is a type of pointer value, but pointer values don't point at values; they point at objects or functions. `&a` is different to `a` because the two pointers point at different objects; one points at `a` and the other points at `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all I knew what's wrong with it.

In fact I created a pointer in memory by `int* a = &b;` but I thought I didn't so it's my mistake.

But what I thought that you cannot output the address of something that does not exist in memory like `cout<<&(&a)`,the compiler will tell you that "&" operator need a l-value variable.

And if you want to output the address of pointer to a, you define a pointer to pointer variable `int **p2p=&a`, and then you can `cout<<&p2p` , it works.